# Why stopTimer() method does not target the Timer object created from setTimer

Tags: javascript

Hi I am taking a course on codeHS and one of the lesson is using Timer to animate the object. So the method is `setTimer(fn,DELAY)` and `stopTimer(fn)`. `fn` is the name of the method which should be run every `DELAY` time. My confusion lies in the fact that I don't understand why `stopTimer(fn)`pass in the method fn to stop a timer. Shouldn't stopTimer() method have a parameter that targets the actual timer object that is created. This is not the case but instead stopTimer used fn or the method that define an object property as parameter to stop the original timer. This is where my confusion lies

Comment: I can't say I've heard of these methods. `set`/`clearInterval` works as you describe. To stop it, you pass the timer Id to `clearInterval`.

Comment: see that is precisely my point clearInterval  the stop target the timer id but the stop method of codehs targets the animation method instead. Would it be helpful if I copy and paste the code?

Comment: Please show us the code of that `Timer` thing or link its documentation.

Comment: I can show you the code how it is use but I can't show you the documentation. If I see the documentation I don't think I need to ask this question the begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are no `setTimer`or `stopTimer`in native javascript. If you are using some framework for this timer, you need to clearify this in the question.

For native javascript here is an example using `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.

```
var timer = setInterval(someFunction, 1000);
clearInterval(timer);
```

[Here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hWlZLfW56n964bbCHPsg?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can you show me how to use another method as parameter to stop the object timer like above?

Comment: No. It is not possible to stop an interval timer from the function alone. You need the ID of the assigned timer. See [w3schools Window clearInterval method(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) for details.

Comment: @AnotherRandomUser Your teacher seems to have created his own weird version if he's expecting you to use those functions. I don't know how you could possibly stop a timer with a function though.